# Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: monte-carlo

I am running a probabilistic analysis for civil engineering purposes(I am finding the failure probability of a structure). I am using three methods: FOSM, FORM and Monte Carlo. I get similar failure probabilities from all 3methods, however, the mean and standard deviation of the performance function that I am optimizing are higher in the case of Monte Carlo. Is this expected?